# ffmpeg record Xvfb and pulseaudio got sync problem

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, xvfb, pulseaudio

I using ffmpeg to record Xvfb and audio from pulseaudio. Sometime the video output has the audio ahead of video ( sometime normal - it happen randomly ). The flow like this

```
ffmpeg 
|-> video : Xvfb -> Firefox
|-> audio : pulsesaudio
```

So I don't know where this issue come from : ffmpeg or Xvfb or Firefox or pulseaudio
I already updated ffmpeg to latest version. Tried to config pulsesaudio `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`. Nothing help.